# How to debug a C program using SDK on xilinx?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, fpga, xilinx-edk

I'm using an **Atlys spartan 6 xc6slx45**,I have to debug this code :

```
1-#include "stdio.h"
2-int main (void)
3-{
4-// Initialization of the necessary variables
5-int i,j,k;
6-// Initialization of source A and B 4x4 matrices and result C matrix
7-int a[4][4]={ {1,2,3,4},
8-{1,2,3,4},
9-{1,2,3,4},
10-{1,2,3,4}};

11-int b[8][8]={ {1,2,3,4},
12-{1,2,3,4},
13-{1,2,3,4},
14-{1,2,3,4}};

15-int c[8][8]={ {0,0,0,0},
16-{0,0,0,0},
17-{0,0,0,0},
18-{0,0,0,0}};

19-xil_printf("‐‐ Entering main() ‐‐\r\n");
20-for (i=0; i<4; i++ )
21-{
22-for (j=0; j<4; j++)
23-{
24-for(k=0; k<4; k++)
25-{
26-c[i][j]=c[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
27-}
28-}
29-}
30-for (i=0; i<4; i++ )
31-{
32-for (j=0; j<4; j++)
33-{
34-xil_printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
35-}
36-xil_printf("\n\r");
37-}
38-return 0;
39-}
```

I add a toggle to the `5,7,11,15,26`. I went to `Run-->Debug Configurations --> Xilinx C/C++ application(GDB)` ---> `Build configurations:Debug` then I pressed `Debug` button. I got this error :

```
No source available for "_start()".
Target failed:Target is not responding(timeout).
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/SDK-debugging-becoming-almost-unusable-in-14-1/td-p/268854) thread?

Comment: Which version of ISE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is one of those truly annoying SDK bugs that has been around for a long time, if you read the document here:
[SDK Limitations  FAQ](https://www.xilinx.com/support.html#documentation)

You will find a section that describes one of the limitations of the SDK:

> **Xilinx C/C++ Debugger (GDB) debugger hangs when the Disassembly view is open.**

Close all your disassembly windows and try again.

One other thing that can cause problem is that you have too many breakpoints, try to remove them and reset the CPU before starting a new debug session.

Hope it helps!