# no source available for"_start()"

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-edk

I write a program using sdk on xilinx but when I debug it I got this error

```
No source available for "_start()"
```

After that:

```
Timeout not responding.
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727078/how-to-debug-a-c-program-using-sdk-on-xilinx) out.

Comment: I saw it but the problem still exist.